# « À » ou « dans » dans « Je ne sais pas ce que ma chatte a ces temps-ci, elle a la manie de dormir dans/à des endroits inhabituels ? »

Tags: choix-de-mot, reformulation

Je ne sais pas ce qu’a ma chatte ces temps-ci, elle a la manie de dormir dans/à des endroits inhabituels.

Je me pose aussi la même question, mais cette fois-ci avec les verbes « aller » et « s’avachir ».

> Je ne sais pas ce qui se passe avec ma chatte, elle a la manie d’aller/de s’avachir dans/à des endroits inhabituels.

Les reformulations sont les bienvenues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

L'usage est assez clair lorsque le verbe dénote une action qui se fait dans le lieux donné. Par exemple on dit « dormir dans un champ » mais pas « dormir à un champ » ; « dormir dans des hôtels » est normalement ce que les gens disent mais  « dormir à des hôtels » ne se trouve pas. On trouve « vécu dans des endroits » mais pas « vécu à des endroits ». « Dormi dans des endroits » est usuel, mais « dormi à des endroits » ne se trouve pas. Il y a quand même des exceptions puisqu'il faut dire « dormir **à/sur** la plage » et « dormir sur la terrasse » et pas « dormir dans la plage » et « dormir à la terrasse ».

Il vaut mieux utiliser « dans des endroits », mais « à des endroits » ne me semble pas faux.

« S'avachir dans » convient pour « endroit » ; (pour d'autres noms on trouve aussi « sur ».) Par exemple on trouve « s'affaler dans » mais pas « s'affaler à ». Lorsqu'on dit « s'avachir à » il ne s'agit plus de l'idée d'être supporté entièrement par ce sur quoi on s'avachit mais d'y être seulement appuyé ou seulement localisé parmi d'autres choses.

- Ils allèrent s'avachir à une table basse dans un coin sombre.
- Combien de fois qu'il est venu s'avachir à ma table, pour me causer, m'expliquer, me supplier !
- Peu après, Ruth descendit l'escalier d'un pas lourd et vint s'avachir à la table de la cuisine
- Gabriel plongea distraitement le regard dans Le Parisien tandis que Léon , le berger allemand de la maison , vint s'avachir à ses pieds.
- s'avachir à/sur la plage, à/sur la terrasse (ex : il s'est avachi à la terrasse d'un café)
  Ne pas confondre « à » avec « à » dans les locutions prépositives suivantes : à côté de, à l'intérieur de, à l'autre bout de,…